# How to properly utilize a doinBackground() method in order to retrieve RSS items

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, rss

Right now I'm creating an RSS reader and primarily just trying to get items's title and description to display on the ListView. I tested it without RSS data earlier and confirmed that the app properly lists items I created. However after attempting the same with data from an RSS, I'm encountering issues with retrieving the actual RSS data as well how to use the doinBackground method.

After reading Google's documentation regarding doinBackground, I understand that it's class (Async) allows for background operations to be performed and have their results displayed in the UI thread. However, I'm having problems in general with pulling RSS data and also how doinBackground() could fit into my code. Any ideas on how to properly retrieve the data and use doinbackground() effectively?

The classes of code that I'm having trouble with are Headlines and RSSManager. Here's the code:

Headlines Fragment

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Headlines extends Fragment {
EditText editText;
Button gobutton;
ListView listView;

public Headlines() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_headlines, container, false);
    editText = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.urlText);
    gobutton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.goButton);
    listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    RSSFeedManager rfm = new RSSFeedManager();
    News [] news = new News[100]; // i shouldnt have to set the size of the array here since I did it in getFeed() in RSSFeedManager.java
    try {
        news = rfm.getFeed(String.valueOf(new URL("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_world.rss")));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    RssAdapter adapter = new RssAdapter(this.getActivity(),news);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    /*gobutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });*/
    return v;
}

}
```

RSSFeedManager

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class RSSFeedManager extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
public URL rssURL;
News[] articles;

public News[] getFeed(String url) {
    try {
        String strURL = url;
        rssURL = new URL(url);
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(rssURL.openStream());

        //using Nodelist to get items within the rss, then creating
        //a News array the same size of the amount of items within the rss
        //then setting up a temporary "News" item which will be the temp object
        //used for storing multiple objects that contain title and description
        //of each item
        NodeList items = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
        News[] articles = new News[items.getLength()];
        News news = null;

        //traverse through items and place the contents of each item within an RssItem object
        //then add to it to the News Array
        for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {
            Element item = (Element) items.item(i);
            news.setTitle(getValue(item, "title"));
            news.setDescription(getValue(item, "description"));
            articles[i] = news;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return articles;
}

public String getValue(Element parent, String nodeName) {
    return parent.getElementsByTagName(nodeName).item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
    String rssURL = url[0];
    URL urlTemp;
    try {
        //pulling the url from the params and converting it to type URL and then establishing a connection
        urlTemp = new URL(rssURL);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlTemp.openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();
        /*
        *im thinking i need to call the getFeed() method
        *after establishing the httpurlconnection however
        *I also thought I may just need to move the getFeed()
        *code within doinBackground. Lost at this point due to the
        * return types of getFeed and doinBackground
        */
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: You're not using `AsyncTask` correctly, the `doInBackground(...)` method is not executed because you never call the `execute(...)` method on the `RSSFeedManager` instance that you've created.

Comment: @Titus, thanks I forgot to include that. however at this time my doInBackground method doesn't accomplish anything since I'm unsure of what to include in it aside from the HTTPURLConnection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After picking each line of code apart, I figured out some of the problems with my RSSFeedManager class,`doInBackground()` method and Headlines class.

Starting with the RSSFeedManager, there were a few problems here. I instantiated instantiated `News [] articles` as a class variable and then redefined it within the `getFeeds()` method. Obviously this was causing some problems and would return `articles` back as null. I also removed `strURL` and `rssURL` because I was going about this all the wrong way. There wasn't any need to pass a URL to `getFeeds()` instead I needed to pass it the XML from a URL. I also touched up the code a little bit to make use of the News class's constructor.

Here's the fixed code for RSSFeedManager:

```
public class RSSFeedManager{

News[] articles;

public News[] getFeed(String html) {
    try {
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes()));

        NodeList items = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
        articles = new News[items.getLength()];

        for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {
            Element item = (Element) items.item(i);
            News news = new News(getValue(item, "title"),getValue(item, "description").substring(0,100),"");
            articles[i] = news;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("EXCEPTION PARSING",e.toString());
    }
    return articles;
}

public String getValue(Element parent, String nodeName) {
    return parent.getElementsByTagName(nodeName).item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
}
}
```

As I mentioned before hand, I realized RSSFeedManager should be receiving XML from a URL rather than a URL itself and that a new class is where the `doInBackground()` should take place. Essentially the `doInBackground()` method with the Downloader class (which extends `AsyncTask` is receiving the inputted url and then collecting the XML from that RSS url.

Here's the Downloader class

```
public class Downloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String result ="";
    try{
        URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line = "";
        while((line=reader.readLine())!= null){
            result= result + line;
        }
        connection.disconnect();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error fetching", e.toString());
    }

    return result;
}
}
```

So after both of those classes were taken care of, I knew I needed to fix some things around in my Headlines class. I originally brute forced the code to test to make sure articles from the RSS feed were properly displaying and they did and then set out to implement it properly. To remind people, the intent of the program is to display articles from an RSS feed which the user specifies by inputting a url into `editText` which is an `EditText` object. Then the user presses `goButton` which is of type `Button` and then lists all of articles of the url from `editText`. I accomplished this by creating an `onClickListener` for `goButton` and creating objects of the `Downloader` and `RssFeedManager` classes in order to call their methods to establish a connection, retrieve the URL's XML, and then parse through it.

Here is a snippet of the Headline class's code where I was able to tie everything together.

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_headlines, container, false);
    editText = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.urlText);
    gobutton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.goButton);
    listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    parent = this.getActivity();
    gobutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RSSFeedManager rfm = new RSSFeedManager();
            String html = "";
            try {
                Downloader d = new Downloader();
                d.execute(editText.getText().toString());
                html = d.get();
                Log.d("HTML CAME BACK", html);
                news = rfm.getFeed(html);
                RssAdapter adapter = new RssAdapter(parent, news);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e("ERROR!!!!!", e.toString());
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                Log.e("ERROR!!!!!!!", e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(parent, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("WEIRD!", e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(parent, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        }
    });
```

All of these changes helped fix the problem and allowed me to progress further into completing this program, as well as learn more about android development.

Comment: You're still not using the `AsyncTask` correctly, this line `d.get();` blocks until the `doInBackground()` method returns and since you're executing `d.get();` on the UI Thread, the GUI will freeze until the pages are downloaded.